# How do I stay logged into Gmail after shutting down my computer if the "stay signed in" box does NOT appear at the sign in?

Tags: gmail

The "stay signed in" check box no longer appears when I log in to my Gmail account. Therefore, every time I go to Gmail after shutting down my computer I have to re-enter the password. I have no idea why the "stay signed in" no longer appears on the Gmail sign-in page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Chrome, you can [sign into Chrome Browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en).

In the top right corner, where the minimize button is (on windows), you will see a picture of a person.  Simply click on the person and sign into your google account and it will keep you signed in between reboots.

This will not work if you are using [Incognito Mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en).  As Incognito Mode will remove all setting when you close the browser session.

Also note the other benefits of signing in.  It will save bookmarks and settings to if you have to reinstall you computer or use a different computer your settings will come back when you sign in to the new computer.